# Is it possible to create a REGEX loop that iterates through a list

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm using the following to find whether a text exist in the sentence and printing out that text:

Example:

```
import re

lst = ['text1','text2','text3']

sent = 'This is a test to find text1 and text3'

my_regex =re.search(r'\b(text1)\b', sent)

print(my_regex.group())

text1
```

Question:

is it possible to create a loop similar to the following that will iterate and update the re.search with each value in the list:

note - The list is likely to expand beyond the three listed in the example

```
for i in lst:
    my_regex =re.search(r'\b(i)\b', sent)
    print(my_regex.group())
```

Comment: You didn't think of using string concatenation? `r'\b' + i + r'\b'`?

Comment: You can search for all three at once: `r'\b(text1|text2|text3)\b'`. Have you tried that?

Comment: The list is likely to expand in the future to a decent size, so typing in all instances wouldn't be practical ( I'll update the original question to include the fact that the list is likely to grow)

Comment: @Barmar I tried this earlier but I guess something was wrong with my code because I just got it to work. Thanks for suggestion / answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new f-strings.

```
for i in lst:
    my_regex =re.search(fr'\b{i}\b', sent)
    print(my_regex.group())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[item for item in lst if re.search(r'\b%s\b' % item, sent)]
```

Or you can use faster solution (~38 times):

```
[s for s in sent.split() if s in lst]
```

Output:

```
['text1', 'text3']
```

Comment: The regexp only matches whole words, this will match any substring.